# No data in the attribute table when creating buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, distance, buffer

I wanted to create a buffer around a polygon using QGIS. This buffer zone is something I will use to estimate the distances between patches of habitat but every time I do so there's no data in the attribute table of the buffer, see an image below.

Is there a way to extract the buffer zone data in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: There is a field called "clumps" in your attribute table, with a value of 1. How did it get there? What specific tool did you use to create your buffer? When I run the Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Buffer tool, all fields are copied.

Comment: There's only one field (clumps) in the shapefile I am using but this field contains several polygons (around 10,000). I tried creating a buffer around them expecting the buffer to be separated from each other. But in the process of creating it even though it generated unconnected polygons they are considered as one unlike the shapefile where I can select individual polygons.

Comment: Did you select 'Dissolve Result'? That would merge the outputs. I just tested it :-)

Comment: @wingnut, I think you can put your comment as an answer

Comment: I did but does that mean even if they are not spacially connected they will still be one data? I kind of wanted to dissolve only those that are spacially connected but will try it too. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The **Vector - Geoprocessing Tools - Buffer** tool in QGIS is applied to all features in a layer. Buffered features can also be dissolved, so that overlapping buffers are not created, if required. This reduces the number of features in the output. The number of items in the attribute table will reflect this.